# When someone gets a face-lift surgery

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Imagine a woman who has had a plastic surgery on her face and has lifted her face. How a native speaker should say it in everyday speech?

For me, the following examples which are direct translations from my language, work, but I have no idea if they are natural or not:

> She looks younger than her age. --- Yea, but I think **sh’s gotten a face-lift**.
>
> She looks younger than her age. --- Yea, but I think **she has done a face-lift**.
>
> She looks younger than her age. --- Yea, but I think **she has lifted her face**.

If they are not natural, please tell me how shall I say it in the most common way?

Comment: The first phrase came to my mind, for a colloquial setting, was *she got her face done*.

Comment: Related. [When someone has a plastic surgery on the face](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/116194/when-someone-has-a-plastic-surgery-on-the-face) see Andrew's answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I certainly read my own thread. :) Please let me know which one works better here.

Comment: "He/she has had work done"

Comment: Lots of usable suggestions here, but to address the question as stated, the first one is definitely the most correct. The others aren't phrases in English, at least not that I've heard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a native English speaker:

She looks younger than her age.
Yeah, but I think she's had a face-lift.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you:

> — She looks younger than she really is.
>   — Yeah, but I think that she's just got one of those facelift surgeries.