# When someone injects Botox to her face

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice, proper-nouns, verbing

Please imagine someone injects Botox to a part of his / her face. What is the most natural way in common English to say it? For me, all of the following examples work, but I have no idea which one works better:

> She's gotten Botox injections in her forehead.
>
> She's Botoxed her forehead.
>
> She's injected Botox in / to her forehead.

If none of them sound natural to you, then I would appreciate it if you could let me know the most natural way to say the same thing.

Comment: related:[When someone has a plastic surgery on the face](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/116194/when-someone-has-a-plastic-surgery-on-the-face)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence 2 sounds the most natural to me:

> She's Botoxed her forehead.

Sentence 1 is a weird mix of formality.  "She's gotten" is informal.  "Botox injections in her forehead" is formal.

Sentence 2 is consistently informal.  The contraction "She's" is informal.  Using a recently-created brand name as a verb is informal.

Sentence 3 is incorrect, if read literally.  Botox injections are performed by medical professionals, not by the patients themselves.  By the way, this sentence should probably have "into" as the preposition, not "in" or "to".

Answer (score 2):

I think a good way to say it is:

> She has had Botox injected into her forehead.
> or
> She's had Botox done.